# Could you tell any function from standard library or anwhere else ,which finds unique translations for input word

Tags: c++

For Instance , I have a list of  translations ,like (`Letter['.']='E'`;)
and I need to get translation by using this list .

Comment: Are you looking for a `std::map<char,char>`?

Comment: You have unlimited space in your question, it is neither SMS nor twitter. Please explain more about what you want to achieve, what your inpuit is, what the desired output is, what code you have already tried, in which way the achieved input is unsatisfactory. Maybe try to do a [mcve], otherwise take the [tour], especially [ask].

Comment: That ^ (`std::map`) along with [`std::transform()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) can do what you want in basically one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of is using a [`std::map<char,char>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to do that:

```
 std::map<char,char> Letter {
        { '.' , 'E' } ,
        { '$' , 'S' } ,
        // ...
     };
 auto found_translation = Letter.find('.');
 if(found_translation != std::end(Letter)) {
     // Do stuff using found_translation->second 
 }
```

or like [@cdhowie proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46028204/could-you-tell-any-function-from-standard-library-or-anwhere-else-which-finds-u#comment79016456_46028204):

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(),
               [Letter](char c) -> char {  
                   return Letter.find(c) != std::end(Letter) ? Letter[c] : c;
               });
```